# How to interpret this standalone "si" clause?

Tags: sens, conjonctions, exclamations

> Tu vas m’aider à gérer tout ça, hein... **Si** je m’attendais à te voir aussi coopératif. Tu as tellement changé.

I just heard the peculiar use of a "si" clause in conversation among my French-speaking friends. I suppose it is somewhat different from saying "***Comme si*** je m’attendais ...", but what does it mean, exactly? I wonder what is the missing main clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In writing, you'd probably see an exclamation mark after this sentence:

> Si je m'attendais à te voir si coopératif !

This construction indicates surprise. The meaning is the same as

> Je ne m'attendais vraiment pas à te voir si coopératif !

Another similar expression:

> Si l'on m'avait dit que tu serais si coopératif ! [sous-entendu : je ne l'aurais pas cru]

Answer (score 2):

Le sens est *je ne m'attendais vraiment pas à te voir aussi coopératif*. La clause manquante est justement quelque chose de si énorme (à la hauteur de la surprise de voir le monsieur si coopératif) qu'on ne peut pas la trouver. On est comme estomaqué.
Si vraiment il devait y avoir une *main clause* alors ce pourrait être quelque chose comme "je serais allé sur la Lune"... Mais c'est trop en faire.

Answer (score 1):

***I wonder what is the missing main clause?***

There isn't any. This use of the conjunction *si*  introduces an exclamation and is meant to show surprise.

You will find a description of this use in the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/si) (IV. B. 1. b1)):

> γ) [Type: si je m'attendais! Marque la surprise] − *Ah! saperlotte, ah! c'est toi, balbutiait Quenu, si je m'attendais, par exemple!... Je t'ai cru mort* (Zola,*Ventre Paris*, 1873, p. 638).

***I suppose it is somewhat different from saying "Comme si je m’attendais ..."***
In this case it is different. *Comme si* implies a comparison. You would have a main clause, e.g.: "*Ce n'est pas comme si je m'attendais à te voir si coopératif*".

---

<sup>In English I'd say: "Fancy you being so cooperative."</sup>
<sup>Found in [Cambridge Word Routes Anglais-Français](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MqyTMW0KZ0IC&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=%22si%20je%20m%27attendais%22%20surprise&source=bl&ots=mAA5XAkCTf&sig=8AGFPZJObCc5aqiDpxMHAIpznTQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3lsi50LDVAhUpJsAKHfIBAVQQ6AEIVDAI#v=onepage&q=%22si%20je%20m%27attendais%22%20surprise&f=false):   Well I never, I didn't expect to meet you today → Pas possible, si je mattendais à te rencontrer aujourd'hui.</sup>